# Function that returns only numbers?

Tags: php

```
function get_only_numbers($string){
    $getonly = str_split("0123456789");
    $string = str_split($string);
    foreach($string as $i => $c){
        if(!in_array($c, $getonly))
            unset($string[$i]);
    }
    return implode("", $string);
}

echo get_only_numbers("U$ 499,50"); // prints 49950
```

This function is supposed to return only the numbers from a string.
Has this function been coded properly?

Comment: Seems to be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Or do you have any problem with the code?

Comment: Wasnt aware codereview existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a single call to [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) can do that as well:

```
preg_replace('/\D+/', '', 'U$ 499,50'); // returns "49950"
```

Answer (score 3):

See [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to further optimize your function so that you don't need the array comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Properly?  It does what it's supposed to...but I prefer regular expressions:

```
function get_only_numbers($string){
    return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string);
}
```

Comment: Using `+` in `/[^0-9]+/` OR `/[^\d]+/` OR `/\D+/` would be little bit more efficient to reduce # of replacements.